# How to Duplicate Database Table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

See this Code:

```
switch(someString)
{
case "11":  
    Con1_1.ConnectionString = conStr;
    Con1_1.Open();
    Dapt1_1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From StdList", Con1_1);
    Dapt1_1.Fill(Dset1_1, "StdList");
    count = Dset1_1.Tables["StdList"].Rows.Count - 1;
    break;
case "12":
    Con1_2.ConnectionString = conStr;
    Con1_2.Open();
    Dapt1_2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From StdList", Con1_2);
    Dapt1_2.Fill(Dset1_2, "StdList");
    count = Dset1_2.Tables["StdList"].Rows.Count - 1;
    break;
}
```

i want to use a database table that can duplicated for 2 cases. please help me to do that.
can i use only one Table in Database for 2 cases or more? or i have to define as many as Table that i need?

Comment: How are these 2 case body differs? I dont see any. Just pass connection string (if your using 2 different Catalog) to a method having the common body code.

Comment: Not clear at all. how many tables do you have in the database? dataset is a collection of datatables so you can add and fill many tables in same dataset. describe better your needs and shape of your data in the database.

Comment: Try to explain (in words, not just code) what you're trying to achieve. You usually get a better answer that way.

Comment: I have a database table for student information it has ID, Name, family, Phone Number & etc. And there is 2 school classes with different student. i need to list these school classes & student Info so i need to 2 database table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to get one set of records from a table if your someString is '11' and a different set of records from a different table if the value of someString is '12'?

If the structure of the records in both tables are the same you could simply add a field (eg 'SchoolClass' to the first table structure to differentiate the records, storing the appropriate value of someString in the column for each record. Then you only need one table - put all the records in that table. To access it the do the following:

```
Con1_1.ConnectionString = conStr;
Con1_1.Open();
Dapt1_1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From StdList WHERE SchoolClass = '" + someString + "'", Con1_1);
Dapt1_1.Fill(Dset1_1, "StdList");
count = Dset1_1.Tables["StdList"].Rows.Count - 1;
```

Comment: no no no man... i just need a copy of my table for another school class

Comment: So you are saying you have a table with student information and you have another table with class information? I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve? Can you describe the situation a little more?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got you.

add two more column in a table, those for class and school. then
you can filter by class and school. But all details will be stored on one table

```
Con1_1.ConnectionString = conStr;
Con1_1.Open();
Dapt1_1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From StdList WHERE class= '" + m_class+ "' AND school='"+m_school+"'", Con1_1);

Dapt1_1.Fill(Dset1_1, "StdList");
count = Dset1_1.Tables["StdList"].Rows.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema proposal and code makes very little sense.

I would recommend that you use a schema that is something like this:

```
#Students
. Id
. ClassId
. Name
. Family
. Phone
. Etc...

#Classes
. Id
. ClassName
. More info you might want about a class...
```

Then you build a method in style with:

```
public DataTable GetStudentsByClass(int classId)
{
    //Set the connection string to the database and open the connection
    Con1_1.ConnectionString = conStr;
    Con1_1.Open();

    //Execute the SQL query
    databaseAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From Students WHERE ClassId = " + classId, Con1_1);

    //Declare a datatable to fill
    DataTable students;

    //Fill the datatable with the results
    databaseAdapter.Fill(students, "Students");

    //Return the filled datatable
    return students;
}

public int GetStudentsInClassCount(int classId)
{
    //Here you can reuse the previous method to get the count, a more optimal way would be to use the SQL count though.
    return GetStudentsByClass(classId).Rows.Count;
}
```

To use it you just do it like this:

```
DataTable students = GetStudentsByClass(1);
```